# gazebo crash on startup

Tags: gazebo, ubuntu, ubuntu-oneiric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have just installed electric on ubuntu oneiric.  I'm finding that gazebo crashes on startup.

console output:

```
:~$ rosrun gazebo gazebo /opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo_worlds/worlds/simple.world 
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 0.10.0

Part of the Player/Stage Project [http://playerstage.sourceforge.net].
Copyright (C) 2003 Nate Koenig, Andrew Howard, and contributors.
Released under the GNU General Public License.

Unsupported shadows type: "stencilAdditive". Supported types are "stencil" and "texture". Not rendering shadows.
directory [/tmp/gazebo-jonathan-0] already exists (previous crash?)
the owner gazebo server (pid=27478) is not running.
deleting the old information of the directory [/tmp/gazebo-jonathan-0]
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::string'
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Backtrace:

```
warning: Can't read pathname for load map: Input/output error.
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Core was generated by `/opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/bin/gazebo /opt/ros/electric/s'.
Program terminated with signal 6, Aborted.
#0  0x00007ff6ec6f43a5 in raise () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ff6ec6f43a5 in raise () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ff6ec6f7b0b in abort () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007ff6ecfb2d7d in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0x00007ff6ecfb0f26 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#4  0x00007ff6ecfb0f53 in std::terminate() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#5  0x00007ff6ecfb104e in __cxa_throw () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#6  0x00007ff6eb35ba7f in libgazebo::IfaceFactory::NewIface(std::string const&) () from /opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/gazebo/lib/libgazebo.so.0.10.0
#7  0x00007ff6edba94d2 in gazebo::Factory::Factory() () from /opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/gazebo/lib/libgazebo_server.so.0.10.0
#8  0x00007ff6edb7f4e2 in gazebo::World::Load(gazebo::XMLConfigNode*, int) () from /opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/gazebo/lib/libgazebo_server.so.0.10.0
#9  0x00007ff6edba4b80 in gazebo::Simulator::Load(gazebo::XMLConfig*, int) () from /opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/gazebo/lib/libgazebo_server.so.0.10.0
#10 0x00007ff6edba5982 in gazebo::Simulator::LoadWorldFile(std::string const&, int) () from /opt/ros/electric/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/gazebo/lib/libgazebo_server.so.0.10.0
#11 0x0000000000464c0b in ?? ()
#12 0x00007fff48ad3fd8 in ?? ()
#13 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11791/gazebo-crash-on-startup/) by [JonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/317/jonw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 586 on 2011-11-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks similar to the current crash we're experiencing on Fedora: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5170 (check out the last bt posted)

---

Originally posted by [Steven Bellens](https://answers.ros.org/users/55/steven-bellens/) with karma: 735 on 2011-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/317/jonw/) on 2011-11-05**:
thanks for the pointer.  I'm going to try it on another i386 oneiric machine I have and see if that produces the same result.